# Rewrite rule to redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

How to redirect any variable(string) to another http://domain2.com/ from http://domain1.com/

First when user enter domain1.com user can view this website domain1.com/
After loading domain1.com/ If user type in address bar "http://popcorn" "http://go"or user should redirect to domain2.com/.

What I want when user enter domain1.com & after loading, if user type variable(string) inluding "http://"  he should redirect to domain2.com

How to write rewrite rule for the above example.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible.
A website has no access to what users are writing in the address bar.

the only thing you can do is redirect http://www.domain1.com/popcorn to http://www.domain2.com.

Comment: Thats right, I agree, But in htaccess by Rewrite rule I think it is possible on apache locally or online.

Comment: This example is simple redirect but advance example             RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(http://)?mail$ [NC]                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yahoo.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Very Funny... :D

But still i can try to atleast make you happy... :)
But this trick only helpful in mozilla...

in address bar type: `about:config`
Be careful in modifying any record into it...

go to `browser.search.defaulturl or defaultenginename`
and change it to your convenience

Comment: but this not for all browser & I can not go to each pc and edit this settings

Comment: exactly what i was saying... this cant be achieve... but you can still do 1 more thing... create a patch of it and ask user to add that patch...

Comment: I think 50% it is possible by Rewrite rule

Comment: .htaccess only work when your request hits the server. and what you are trying to do is not at all requesting server. :)